# sql server sp_monitor overflow issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using sp_monitor in a sql server script to get some values. It is called from c#. However, it returns overflow exception:

**Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.**

Is it because the sql server is up too long? Do I have to restart the SQL server to fix this? Any other solutions? How many days I should restart to avoid this exception?

Thanks

Comment: what is the code your trying to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this in ten year or so. It is (or used to be?) a fairly common issue when a server had been up for approx 49 days. The reason is that `@@CPU_BUSY` overflows, i.e. the number of CPU time increments, or "ticks," the server has been busy since it was started. It is cumulative for all CPUs, so it may exceed the actual elapsed time.

You can debug and hack `sp_monitor`, replacing the offending `integer` with `bigint`, but I'm not sure if that is a good solution to your problem.

My guess is you are using a fairly old SQL Server?

Reboot the server as a temporary fix.

Comment: a weird thing is: this happens on sql2014 running with compatibility of sql2102. I was wondering why it is still not fixed yet. I guess we will have to live with it. thanks